# PHP For iOS Push Notifications, Sometimes More Than 1 Device

Tags: ios, loops, apple-push-notifications, devicetoken

I am building an app in which I am using NSUserDefaults to store various pieces of information, including the deviceToken that is used for APNS on iOS.  The way it is currently working is that a user submits a request, and it adds an entry to an XML, one of the elements in that XML is called deviceToken.  When someone responds to that request, it triggers the PHP at the bottom of the page to send a Push Notification to the deviceToken of that particular request.  My issue is that some people have more than one device, and it would be nice to send the Push Notification to all of that owner's devices.  As you can see in the code below, I have 2 areas for deviceTokens.  If the XML contains 2 device tokens, everything is great.  The issue is that for the ones that there is only 1 token, it will fail to deliver even the one.  How can I fix this PHP so that it will be able to accept 2 deviceTokens, but still deliver if only 1 is available?

```
<?php
$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
 $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
 $title = $_POST['title'];
 $deviceToken = $_POST['deviceToken'];
 $deviceToken2 = $_POST['deviceToken2'];
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.URL.xml") or die("Not loaded!\n");

$passphrase = 'passphrase';

// Put your alert message here:
$message = 'Someone just responded to you!';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Create the payload body
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => $message,
    'sound' => 'default'
    );

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;
$msg2 = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken2) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg2, strlen($msg2));


if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);  
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use the function as a generic one: that is, it accepts a device token object. This could be a single string, or an array of multiple strings.

Then, check whether`$deviceToken` is an array using the `is_array` function. Ref:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

For this, you may have to rewrite small bits of the code. So overall, it would look something like this:

```
if(is_array($deviceToken)) {
    // Iterate over the array and call the same function with each string
    return;
}

// You're code to actually send the push notification just as you have it above.
```